# How can I make a convolution function with double pointer matrices in C?

Tags: c, function, convolution

I need to make a convolution function in C and I'm kind of lost. Basically I need something like:

[image]

My function needs to be prepared for square matrices from 3x3 to even 1000x1000.
This is what I tried:

```
int calcConv(int **matrix, int ** filter,int i, int j){
  int calc=0;

  for(int ii=i ; ii<i+3 ; ii++){             //Fixed posible Infinite Loop
    for(int jj=j ; jj<j+3 ; jj++){
      calc+= matrix[ii][jj] * filter[ii][jj];
    }
  }

  return calc;
}


int ** convolucion(int **matrix, int **filter, int size){
  int i,j;

  int ** convMatrix = (int**)malloc( size * sizeof(int*));

  for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    convMatrix[i]= (int*)malloc( size * sizeof(int));
  }

  for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    for(j=0;j<size;j++){
      convMatrix[i][j]=matrix[i][j];
    }
  }

  for(i=1;i<size-1;i++){
    for(j=0;j<size-2;j++){
      convMatrix[i][j+1]= calcConv(matriz,filter,i-1,j);
    }
  }

  return convMatrix;
}
```

Any help or advice is very appreciate!

Comment: When will a condition like `i<i+3` *ever* become false?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In case of an integer overflow. Okay, that was a lame joke.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: I thought the same and I replaced it with the full calculation but that's not the only problem I'm getting I assume.

Comment: also (minor) `i=i` is useless. You can leave this part of `for` empty:`for( ; <your condition> ; <increment>)`

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Comment: `for (int ii = i; ii < i + 3; ii++)` At least it doesn't have an infinite loop.